# How to check if multiple rows have been selected in a grid

Tags: grid, axapta, multi-select, x++

How can I check if multiple rows have been selected in a grid?

In Dynamics Ax, there a multiselect property that disable button if multiple records have been selected, does the "opposite" exists?

Meaning activating a button only if multiple records have been selected, how can I do this through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless that kind of property exists, it seems you have two things here :

1. check if multiple rows are selected
2. check it every time the selection changes

### Checking for multiple selection

Have a look on [axaptapedia : Multiple grid selections](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Multiple_grid_selections) to count the selected records.

### Checking on selection's change

Look at the InventTable's form where buttons are activated depending on the selection being a bom or not.

Form's methods handling buttons activation like `setBOMRouteEnabled` are called from datasource's method `active`.

Following this model you can check for multiple selection on selection's change.

Comment: Merci pour l'info, j'ai effectivement réussi à me débrouiller avec la méthode active()

Answer (score 1):

The best way to detect this would be like this:

```
FormDataSource  fds = salesTable.dataSource();

if (fds.recordsMarked().lastIndex() > 1)
    info("Multiple records selected");
else
    info("1 or 0 records selected");
```